# iOS Swift 2 - Get path to video in camera roll

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an app that uploads a video on a server and I got to a point where I need to re-run the upload process if a user shuts down the app and openes it again later.

After a user taps on a video, this function gets triggered

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString

    if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie {
        let fileUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL

        // ...
    }

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("someSegue", sender: self)

}
```

But I found out that `fileUrl` points to some temporary reference to the original video and is always different even if the video is the same.

So how can I get real path to the video, which I can save to NSUserDefaults so when a user opens the app again I can access the video again.

Comment: What component are you using to upload the video ? NSUrlSession ?

Answer (score 0):

The UIImagePicker will always compress a video and hands you the NSURL of the temp file given in `info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]`--and it is your responsibility to delete that temp file whether you use it or not.

If you want to use the compressed version, move it to your documents folder and save the path to that in your NSUserDefaults.

If you want the original raw video, get the NSURL in `info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]`. This is the URL to the original ALAsset. Then you'll need to use `PHImageManager().requestImageDataForAsset` or `PHImageManager().requestExportSessionForVideo` to get the data for upload.

Comment: do I have to delete the video at info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] ? Because if I save that URL it is not accessible after the app shuts down and opens again, so it seems to like it was removed from the tmp folder.

Comment: Saving the URL is probably a different problem. Since iOS8, you get a different absolute path to your app on each run. So save the relative URL (I just save the name of the file since I know which folder I keep everything) and then reconstruct a new absolute URL when the file needs to be opened.

But if the file is important to you, do move it from the tmp folder. When the device gets low on storage, iOS will delete tmp and caches without telling you. Sounds like when you are done with the file and it is fully uploaded, you can delete it then.